# How to generate encoded text directly from tf.data.Dataset.from_generator method?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

On [Better performance with the tf.data API](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#the_dataset) Tensorflow tutorial is showed a simple and efficient `Dataset` implementation. When working with text datasets, this implementation would be something like:

```py
class TextDataset(tf.data.Dataset):

    def _generator(dataset_dir, num_samples):
        # Opening the dataset file
        dataset_file = open(dataset_dir, "r")

        for sample_idx in range(num_samples):
            # Reading data (line, record) from the file
            sample = dataset_file.readline()

            yield {"idx": sample_idx, "text": sample}

    def __new__(cls, dataset_dir, num_samples=3):
        return tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
            cls._generator,
            output_types={"idx": tf.dtypes.int64, "text": tf.dtypes.string},
            output_shapes={"idx": (), "text": ()},
            args=(dataset_dir, num_samples,)
        )
```

which generates the following dataset:

```py
{'idx': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=0>,  
 'text': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'sample one'>},

{'idx': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=1>, 
 'text': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'sample two'>},

{'idx': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=int64, numpy=2>, 
 'text': <tf.Tensor: shape=(), dtype=string, numpy=b'sample three'>}

...
```

Now, instead of yield the `text` as a string in the `_generator` method, it would be interesting to return only the identifiers of the string's tokens (encode). This is possible to be done by a `tokenizer`.

So, how to encode the `text` as a list of integers before yield it in the `_generator` method?

**Note**: a working example is available in [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nj11j5U2qqhfb6CD0QRxMhUtUC0U5lUE).